# How to pass a String variable from PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I'm trying to pass a string variable from PHP to Javascript and it is giving me troubles.

I actually pas a number variable as per the code below and it works, but once I introduce (or uncomment) the line `var cityname = <?=$city;?>;` in my javascript code then it doesn't work. I believe it has something to do with the type of data because if I introduce a number like `Scity = 3` in my PHP then it works.

Thank you

I have the following PHP:

```
<?php
    $get_total_rows = 0;
    $city = "London";

    $db = pg_connect("$db_host $db_name $db_username $db_password");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table";
    $results = pg_query($query);

    $get_total_rows = pg_numrows($results); 
?>
```

and I have the following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var track_load = 0; //total loaded record group(s)
//var cityname = <?=$city;?>;
var total_rows = <?=$get_total_rows;?>;

$('#results').load("autoload_process.php", {'rows':total_rows}, function() {track_load++;}); //load first group
```

Comment: As in most programming languages, javascript expects string literals to be quoted `var cityname = '<?=$city;?>';`

Comment: @MarkBaker Or better yet, `var cityname = <?= json_encode($city) ?>;` so it gets escaped if necessary.

Comment: @MarkBaker  thanks, that works

Answer (score 0):

In the case of strings, the content must be between quotes (ex.: val = "content"). Try to do something like this:

```
var track_load = 0; //total loaded record group(s)
var cityname = "<?php echo $city; ?>"; // string
var total_rows = <?php echo $get_total_rows;?>; // number
```